# Replace all numbers except those which are 4 digits long

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling with my regexp, let me explain...

I have a text from which using PHP, I want to turn all the numbers into '###', except those which are 4 digits long. For example:

"In the 1980s, 402 people died in a fire. There were 42345 firemen there. The cost were estimated at $423,232.32"

needs to become:

"In the 1980s, ### people died in a fire. There were ### firemen there. The cost were estimated at $###,###.###"

So I want every numbers that are not years, i.e. not having 4 digits. Ideally, I would like only years beetween 1900 and 2100, but it's complicated enough the way it is I think...

This : ̀̀`/([\d]{1,3})|([\d]{5,})/` is not working, as it thinks that 1980 is 198 then 0...

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Doesn't "There were 4234 firemen..." contain a four digit number?  Why did your expected output convert that to ###?

Comment: It's impossible to know whether a number is a year or not.  Years may not be four digits, and some four digit numbers may not be years

Comment: @DavidO: Because I wrote this example like an idiot. I fixed it ^^

Comment: I know @ExplosionPills, but let's assume in this example that all dates are 4 digits long... It's OK there are some mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)?

```
$s = "In the 1980s, 402 people died in a fire. There were 42345 firemen there. The cost were estimated at $423,232.32";

$replaced = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($match) {
    $n = strlen($match[0]);
    if ($n == 4)
        return $match[0];
    return str_repeat('#', $n);
    // return '###';
}, $s);
// => "In the 1980s, ### people died in a fire. There were ##### firemen there. The cost were estimated at $###,###.##"
```

Comment: Oh, that's what I was looking for! Never heard of this function before. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @PaulinTrognon I'm not sure why you accepted this answer because the original string was `There were 42345 firemen` and ***NOT*** `There were 4234 firemen there`

Comment: @Tuga, I just copied the string literal from the question. It seems like the question was edited in grace time. (See the first comment in the question). I updated the code accordingly. Thank you for the point.

Comment: Yes I edited my question because of DavidO's remark. All is good now :)

Answer (score 2):

Might be a better regex, but using `\b` (word boundary) fixes yours I think:

```
echo preg_replace('/(\b\d{1,3}\b)|(\d{5,})/', '###', $string);
```

You also don't need the character classes `[ ]`.

Comment: That's the easy fix.  @falsetru will replace with the proper number of # characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with preg_replace:

```
$pattern = '~(?:(?!\A)\G|(?<!\d)(?=\d{1,3}+(?>\d{2,})?(?!\d)))\d~';
$txt = preg_replace($pattern, 'x', $txt);
```